# How to create check mark in the table view in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, checkmark

I want to create a check mark in the table view. When I tap the particular row, the check mark is visible, so I want to display the check mark when selected at the particular row. Please guide me and give me some links.

Here my code is,

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

                [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
          }
```

I want to display the accessory type, when I click the particular state(selected only one row at a time).

Thanks.

Comment: Gosh 6000+ views without actual answer??!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814060/check-uncheck-buttons-in-uitableviews-cell/12814962#12814962

Comment: This is covered in the accepted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959950/iphone-uitableview-cellaccessory-checkmark -- in fact this question is a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you delegate is set properly for this controller and that the table view is connected to the delegate on the controller:

```
tableview.delegate = self;
```

After that your code should work.  I tried your code in my own app and it worked (minus the self.tableview, since my tableview is not a property of the controller.)

Answer (score -2):

So you can do this by showing an image of check mark in your row.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    int x = tableView.frame.size.width - 20; //or whatever x coordinate
    int y = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].frame.size.height - 10;
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 20, 20)];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] addSubview:imgView];
}
```

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel, IOS already has the desired feature with cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark