# iPhone :UITableView CellAccessory Checkmark

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios4

In iPhone App  on click of table view cell I want to display Table view  cell Accessory type Check mark for that on didSelectRowAtIndexPath i am writing code

```
if(indexPath.row ==0)
{
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
 }
```

and displaying  check marks.

but in my case i wnt to allow user to check only on cell at a time  means if user select other row then that row should checked and  previously checked  should be unchecked

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView Checkmark ONLY ONE Row at a Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192908/uitableview-checkmark-only-one-row-at-a-time)

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Keep track, in an instance variable, of which row is checked.
When the user selects a new row, first uncheck the previously checked row,
then check the new row and update the instance variable.

Here is more detail. First add a property to keep track of the currently checked row. It's easiest if this is an `NSIndexPath`.

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    ...
    NSIndexPath* checkedIndexPath;
    ...
}

...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath* checkedIndexPath;
...

@end
```

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` add the following:

```
if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else 
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

How you code your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will depend on the behavior you want.
If there always must be a row checked, that is, that if the user clicks on an already checked row use the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Uncheck the previous checked row
    if(self.checkedIndexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView
                     cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.checkedIndexPath];
        uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

If you want to allow the user to be able to uncheck the row by clicking on it again use this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Uncheck the previous checked row
    if(self.checkedIndexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView
                    cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.checkedIndexPath];
        uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
    {
        self.checkedIndexPath = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Well thought out. Thorough. Great use of code examples. Well done and thanks for the great contribution!

Comment: You should add `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];` in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath `

Comment: @KaiBurghardt Nope, I shouldn't UITableView will do that for you.

Comment: It is crashing if the uncheckCell is not in the visiblecells on tableView.

Comment: @umakanta Can you post more info? Where is it crashing? Why?

Comment: let You have stored the indexpath in checkedIndexPath. Now you scroll the tableview and the checkedIndexPath's cell is not visible.
( i.e.  the cell became nil because of dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier )

In this scenario, in the if loop you have done   
UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView
                    cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.checkedIndexPath];

so uncheckCell is nil now. So it is crashing at this time

Comment: It is perfectly legal to use a nil object in Objective C

Answer (score 5):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *newCell =[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    int newRow = [indexPath row];
    int oldRow = [lastIndexPath row];
    if (newRow != oldRow)
    {
        newCell = [tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: lastIndexPath]; 
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        lastIndexPath = indexPath;  
    }
}
```

For reference take a look at this [discussion](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/24240-uitableviewcellaccessorycheckmark-one-checkmark-time.html)

Answer (score 3):

this is a simple solution that worked for me:

**in your .h file declare:**

```
NSIndexPath *checkedCell;
```

**then in your .m file add:**

```
        if (checkedCell == indexPath) {
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        } else { 
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone; 
}
```

**to the *cellForRowAtIndexPath* method and**

```
checkedCell = indexPath;
[tableView reloadData]
```

**to the *didSelectRowAtIndexPath* method.**

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

I worked on your problem and got a solution

in .h file

```
int rowNO;
    NSIndexPath *lastIndexPth;
```

in . m file

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
    if (rowNO!=indexPath.row) {
        rowNO=indexPath.row;        
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPth].accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        lastIndexPth=indexPath;
    }
```

I hope this might help you...

Answer (score 2):

its simple

in .h

```
NSIndexPath   checkedCell;
```

In .m

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath


if ([checkedCell isEqual:indexPath]) 

{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;


} else
{ 
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone; 
}
```

in
didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
checkedCell = indexPath;

[tableView reloadData]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store `NSIndexPath` of the checked row as the class variable, whenever you try to the others row just access the previously checked row using the  `NSIndexPath` variable stored as class variable and unchecked that.

Check the below post

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/24240-uitableviewcellaccessorycheckmark-one-checkmark-time.html

Answer (score 1):

Add to your `UITableViewDataSource` delegate variable `NSIndexPath *checkedIndex`. Add to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
checkedIndex = indexPath;
[tableView reload];
```

And change your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
cell = .. // init or dequeue
if ([indexPath isEqualTo:checkedIndex])
{
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this one solves your problem :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    int newRow = [indexPath row];
    int oldRow = (lastIndexPath != nil) ? [lastIndexPath row] : -1;
    
    if (newRow != oldRow)
    {
        UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
                                    indexPath];
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        
        UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: 
                                    lastIndexPath]; 
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        lastIndexPath = indexPath;
    }
    
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```