# How to save the state UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have two ViewController.

- FirstViewController
- SecondViewController

In First ViewController  exists `UITableView`

When I select the row appears Second TableView.
There also have `UITableView`.

When you select an item in Second Tableview check mark appears

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

Then when I click back
Again, choose the appropriate line in the First TableView.
A check mark that I set in the Second Tableview disappears.

How do I do that it did not disappear?
I need to save the state.

Comment: Have you searched Stack Overflow for an answer to this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120696/how-to-save-tableview-cells-checkmark-after-reload-view-use-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 2):

A `UITableViewCell` is just a *view*. It does not save state. You should save the state of the application into a *model* object at the time the second table view is getting closed. So you can restore the state from the *model* when needed. For simple models use container classes like NSArray or NSDictionary, for complex data structures create a NSObject subclass.