# How to store, retrieve check or unchecked cells

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to save the checkmark that i place on a cell and then retrieve it. I have 11 cells in that section.

I tried to use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120696/how-to-save-tableview-cells-checkmark-after-reload-view-use-nsuserdefaults) as a guide and it works.  But i want only need one checkmark to be saved rather than many.

And also i want to set checkmark for all cells by default. How would i achieve this

**My Code :**

```
- (NSString *)getKeyForIndex:(int)index{
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"KEY%d",index];
}

- (BOOL) getCheckedForIndex:(int)index {
if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:[self getKeyForIndex:index]] boolValue]==YES) {
 return YES;
}
else
{
  return NO;
}
}

- (void) checkedCellAtIndex:(int)index
{
 BOOL boolChecked = [self getCheckedForIndex:index];

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!boolChecked] forKey:[self getKeyForIndex:index]];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

      if(section == 4) {
         if([self getCheckedForIndex:indexPath.row]==YES) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
          }
          else
          {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
          }
      }
 }


 return cell;
 }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  UITableViewCell* cell = nil;

   NSString *key = [_keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
   NSArray *name = [_names objectForKey:key];

   static NSString *MyCellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

   if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:MyCellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = [name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(section == 4) {
   [self checkedCellAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   if([self getCheckedForIndex:indexPath.row]==YES)
   {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
   }
   else
   {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
   }
    }

  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: What did you try? Show your code.

Comment: You are doing it wrong.  Cells are the *View* in *MVC* and are for presentation and user interaction only.  The checkmark is checked based on data in the *Model*, so if you follow *MVC* you will have quick, convenient, access to whatever condition set the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can be tricky: maintain one array same to tableview datasource array.

Say for example you have `NSMutableArray *mutArrNames` which `tableview datasource`. Now `NSMutableArray *mutArrNamesCheckList` which shows which one is checked or not:

Initially nothing is `selected` so add 0 to uncheck one:

```
for(int i =0; i<[mutArrNames count];i++)
{
    [mutArrNamesCheckList addObject:@"0"];
}
```

Now use like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if(section == 4) {
     //check from mutArrNamesCheckList's list if cell is check one or not
     if([[mutArrNamesCheckList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue] == 1) //checked one
     {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
     }
     else //unchecked one
     {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
     }
   }
  }
  return cell;
}
```

---

Here it can be used according to your requirement like allow multiple selection or single selection:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //get cell object
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   if(section == 4) 
   {
      if([[mutArrNamesCheckList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue] == 1) //checked one
      {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        //replace 0 with 1 as check one
        [mutArrNamesCheckList replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"0"];
      }
      else //unchecked one
      {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        //replace 1 with 0 as uncheck one
        [mutArrNamesCheckList replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"1"];
      }
   }
}
```

For `selection` and `unselection` of all `cell` add this in button's action method. Use this :

```
//remove all as new objects will be added
[mutArrNamesCheckList removeAllObjects];
if(!btnCheckAll.selected)//selected property used - default is no so all not selected
{
   //make all selected
   for(int i =0; i<[mutArrNames count];i++)
   {
    [mutArrNamesCheckList addObject:@"1"];
   }
   //change buttons image here
}
else
{
   //make all unselected
   for(int i =0; i<[mutArrNames count];i++)
   {
    [mutArrNamesCheckList addObject:@"0"];
   }
   //change buttons image here
}

//tableView reload
[yourtableView reloadData];

btnCheckAll.selected = !btnCheckAll.selected;
```

---

Add `mutArrNamesCheckList` in `AppDelegate` to be `visible` in whole Application.

So remove iteration we done on top of above answer in our viewcontroller as we didn't wanted to use globally.

### Edit

Added `toggling` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` + clicked select all button, all cell is checked else unchecked.

Comment: @user3571918 check my answer's again as added toggling in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: thanks. i had select all UIButton also.  if i clicked select all button, all cell is checked else unchecked.

Comment: checkmark is not saved when i close the view controller and open again.

Comment: @user3571918 Add mutArrNamesCheckList in AppDelegate to be visible in whole Application

Comment: where i put this for(int i =0; i<[mutArrNames count];i++)
{
    [mutArrNamesCheckList addObject:@"0"];
}

Comment: because this for loop is initial, when i opens the app this for is working instead of saved one.

Comment: So remove for loop from viewcontrollers if added added so it will maintain array state as its as array is gobal variable.

Comment: if suppose i remove for loop, i got this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51581/discussion-between-prince-peaceful-warrior-and-user3571918)