# How to allow only one cell to be clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to add a tick next to a user selection to indicate that the user has guessed at a particular place.

Currently, my logic allows for all cells to be clicked as can be seen below;

[image]

How can I limit the user to only have one selection enabled at any one time? I was thinking of having a variable (say an int) to track the currently selected - this way i can remove the tick in the correct places. However, I would like to know

1) is this the best way to do it and

2) How do i unselect (unhighlight) a previously selected cell.

Thanks

Would I need a class variable to see if it is assigned, if so then take do some log

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView Checkmark ONLY ONE Row at a Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192908/uitableview-checkmark-only-one-row-at-a-time)

Answer (score 2):

Limit the selection to one by setting

```
yourtableView.allowsMultipleSelection=false
```

Comment: The OP is using Swift.

Answer (score 1):

You could easy use:

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
```

Comment: apparently this will not work - 2 reasons the first being on the storyboard selection is set to single already and secondly , when i use the code you posted in the viewdidload method it warns me saying `'UITableView' does not have a member named 'setAllowsMultipleSelection'`

Comment: Use tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false