# Can't uncheck checkmark set in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a view controller where you can change your gender.  I have a tableview loaded with an array that just has two strings, Male or Female.

If the user was originally set as female, then there's a checkmark on the Female cell. Then when you tap the Male cell, the  Male cell should get checked and the female cell should get unchecked.

**My logic is almost working, but when I first tap on an unchecked cell (Male cell), the checked cell doesn't uncheck (so both Male and Female are checked).**  But then after I select a cell again, it works as desired.

How do I fix this bug... it only occurs the first time I tap on an unchecked cell, then works normally.

I went through a lot of SO links but still getting the same result.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"genderCell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.genderArray[indexPath.row];

    if (([UserParseHelper currentUser].gender = @"Female"))
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
    }
    else if (([UserParseHelper currentUser].gender = @"Male"))
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

[image]

Comment: you answer lies here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192908/uitableview-checkmark-only-one-row-at-a-time .

Comment: @MayYang Write all  code from cellForRowAtIndexPath method to didSelectRowAtIndexPath...    except return statement.

Answer (score 0):

All goes same just Change gender of current user in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row==0)
        [UserParseHelper currentUser].gender = @"Male";
    else if(indexPath.row==1)
        [UserParseHelper currentUser].gender = @"Female";
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

No need of `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` method

```
/*-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}*/
```