# RadioButton inside Tableview cell iOS

Tags: ios, radio-button, tableview, selection

I have followed [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/radiobutton) tutorial for RadioButton.I have integrated it with tableview.The problem is that when I select table row then radio button does not get selected. It gets selected only when I click on RadioButton. I want the radio button to get selected when table row is selected.The code is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    }
    RadioButton *rb1 = [[RadioButton alloc] initWithGroupId:@"Group" index:indexPath.row];
    rb1.frame = CGRectMake(20,13,22,22);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:rb1];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"ABC";
    return cell;
}
```

[RadioButton with Tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0BMi.png)

Comment: put your selection code in -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Set tag to your Btn in "cellforRowAtIndexpath"

```
rb1.tag=101;
```

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath  ->

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:101]; 
 btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
btn.Selected = YES;
 [btn handleButtonTap:self];
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not able to set the button isSelected:YES.

Comment: On clicking radio button the sender value is <UIButton: 0x7f943adecf40; frame = (0 0; 22 22); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f943aded1d0> whereas when i click the tableview cell then sender value is <RadioButton: 0x7f943adec800; frame = (20 13; 22 22); opaque = NO; tag = 101; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f943adecc00>>

Comment: UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:101];     with this you can access your table's seleced row Button(rbi Button(Index)),

Comment: We have used the radio button from the above mentioned tutorial.The code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath is - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
btn.selected = YES;

NSLog(@"Button : %@",btn);
[self radioButtonSelectedAtIndex:indexPath.row inGroup:@"Group"];
RadioButton *rb = [[RadioButton alloc] init];
//[rb handleButtonTap:self];
}

Comment: this is complicated Library ,You can use simple button  to Achieve this functionality, check updated Answer

Comment: how to achieve radio button functionality then.

Comment: if you want only one row selected At time   -->http://stackoverflow.com/a/18002009/4970453

Comment: Thanks. pastie.org/10934067 fulfilled my need.

Answer (score 1):

do the following code on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

**Objective C**

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor redColor]] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        btn.selected = YES;
        NSLog(@"Button : %@",btn);
    }



    - (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return image;
    }
```

Comment: I have added radio button in contentView of tableview cell. It is not a custom cell. So how to access the radio button in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: you should assign tag to your button (suppose 10), now you can get button like this "var yourbutton = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(10) as! UIButton" Once you get yourbutton rest of code are same

Comment: I tried this but it is not able to set the button isSelected:YES. It is throwing error unrecognised selector sendt to instance

Comment: We have used the radio button from the above mentioned tutorial.The code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath is - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
btn.selected = YES;

NSLog(@"Button : %@",btn);
[self radioButtonSelectedAtIndex:indexPath.row inGroup:@"Group"];
RadioButton *rb = [[RadioButton alloc] init];
//[rb handleButtonTap:self];
}

Comment: This is also not working. Giving this error : [RadioButton setBackgroundImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: There seems to be a mis-connection, please check this line UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:101]; giving you UIButton

Comment: No, When i log btn it gives RadioButton instance.