# Disable textfield for other table view cells, when one of the cell is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `textField` on custom cell in a `tableView`. When one of the `cell` is selected I am able to disable `textField` for that particular `cell` by using set selected method.

```
(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated { 
   [super setSelected:selected animated:animated]; 
if (selected) {
   self.accountNameTxtField.enabled = NO; 
} else { 
   self.accountNameTxtField.enabled = YES; 
   } 
}
```

The requirement is to disable `textField` for other cells when any one of the `cell` is selected. Please guide me on this, Thanks.

Comment: first disable all textfield than enable particular textfield so this way is easy

Comment: - (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}

Comment: try this code for enable particular textfield

Comment: Hi there, Do you want me to comment the above code in custom cell and try this in table view?

Comment: Do you want all your `UITextField` disabled at the beginning and should only be enabled once user clicks the cell?

Comment: When cell is seleted, i have a delete operation on tool bar at that time i shoud disable text field-  i have achieved this with above code. Now when one cell is selected that text field of that selected cell is disabled. i want to disable other text fields as well

Comment: So, you mean the cell which is selected should have TextField enable and other must be disable. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use instance variable, you could use indexPath.

When user select any cell, set value of that instance variable to selected indexPath.

And reloadTable.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check if current indexPath is selected indexPath, if yes enable textField else disable it.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Can you be more elaborative.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15426787/3411787) looks almost similar, just assume enabled textField instead of checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

**Create button on tableview cell and enable or disable textfield on tableview or can apply this logic on tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
-(void) btnClick:(id)sender
{
 UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tblView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
NSLog(@"table view row is ----%ld",indexPath.row);

 if (btn.isSelected == false) 
 {
    [btn setSelected:true];
   [selectRow addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",indexPath.row]];
    self.accountNameTxtField.enabled = yes;
   //selectRow is NSMutableArray
 }
  else 
 {  [btn setSelected:false];
    [selectRow removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",indexPath.row]];
    self.accountNameTxtField.enabled = no;
 }
 }

   [tbleview relaoddata];
 if ([selectRow containsObject:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%ld",indexPath.row]])
 {  
 accountNameTxtField.enabled = yes; 
 }
else
{  
 accountNameTxtField.enabled = NO; 
}
```

Comment: It is confusing, You are creating button on btn action.

Comment: You can make text field on uitableview cell and did select can use same logic. You need check contain object  in cell for rowindex method

Answer (score 0):

Use your Data to do this, you must be having some data in for of array containing dictionaries, or class object, I am demonstrating Class Object.

Say you have a Class object `DataClass` create a BOOL property say `textFieldSelected`, now follow the steps

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    DataClass *object=[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    [cell.textField setTag:indexPath.row];

    cell.textField.delegate=self;

    cell.textField.enabled=object.textFieldSelected;

    return cell;
}
```

Now when you select a row

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    for(DataClass *object in self.dataArray){
        object.textFieldSelected=NO;
    } 
    DataClass *object=[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    object.textFieldSelected=YES;
    [tableView reloadData];

}
```

Initially you can set `textFieldSelected=YES;` so that all the textFields are enabled. You can wish to play with object and it will work that way. All the best.

Comment: Hi there. thanks for responding, Shall i create property as non atomic, assign?

Comment: YES because it is BOOL

Comment: i created that property. when i select cell, cell is not selected. Shall i comment my above code in custom cell.

Comment: @Sadik Yes that might be overriding the call.

Comment: Add this `[self.tableView setAllowsSelection:YES];` in `viewDidLoad` and check.

Comment: I have these two lines in view did loadself.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;

Answer (score 0):

Finally i managed to find the solution with integer cell selection count.

cell selection count gets increased in will select row at index path method and set that value in NsuserDefaults.

```
selectedIndex++;

NSString *valueToSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)selectedIndex];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"SelectedIndexString"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

cell selection count gets decreased in didDeselectRowAtIndexPath method and set that value in NsuserDefaults.

selectedIndex--;

In my custom table view cell class in textFieldDidBeginEditing method get the stored value from NsUserDefaults and act upon.

NSString *SelectedIndexString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"SelectedIndexString"];

```
NSLog(@"%ld",(long)SelectedIndexString);
NSInteger SelectedIndexCount = [SelectedIndexString integerValue];

if (SelectedIndexCount) {
    self.accountNameTxtField.enabled = NO;
}
else{
    self.accountNameTxtField.enabled = YES;

}
```

Thanks you so much guys. Thanks for your time.