# UITableViewCell Checkmark - How to save and retrieve indexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Following a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959950/iphone-uitableview-cellaccessory-checkmark), I was trying to get my tableView cell selection right, with saving and other stuff.

I've making it toggle, but can't save the indexPath and retrieve it to display the selection even when the user leaves the view or restarts the app.

Here's the code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath* lastIndexPath;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ...
    if([self.lastIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    ...
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if(self.lastIndexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView
                                        cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.lastIndexPath];
        uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    if([self.lastIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
    {
        self.lastIndexPath = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        self.lastIndexPath = indexPath;
    }


    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.lastIndexPath.row] forKey:@"selectedCell"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}
```

How can I save the indexPath and retrieve it to display the selection even after the user closes and reopens the view?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you only need single selection, you don't need `selArray`. Just track the selected index path.

Comment: I've tried that, but I've been unable to save indexPath and retrieve check status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this in `viewWillAppear`.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSNumber *lastRow = [defaults objectForKey:@"selectedCell"];
if (lastRow) {
    self.lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow.integerValue inSection:0];
}
```

When you restart the app, you should get the `lastIndexPath` from `NSUserDefaults`, otherwise it is nil.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! 
Working perfectly. I can give the bounty in 12h

Answer (score 0):

You should do two things:

1) In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, reload the previously selected row if it is visible
2) In cellForRowAtIndexPath, do a check in there if indexpath.row is the same as your selected cell.  If it is, give it the check mark, if not then don't

Comment: There is no need to reload the table view when a row is selected. Just reload the previously selected row if it is visible.