# how to stop another rows to be select after select a row in uitableview

Tags: uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

In tableview selcting a row in didselectrow i used this

[iPhone :UITableView CellAccessory Checkmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959950/iphone-uitableview-cellaccessory-checkmark/5960016#5960016)

by selecting one row i'm callling a webservice

PROBLEM : i want only one row selection not another by next time what to do 
stop another rows to being selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `tableView.allowsSelection = false` to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and then re-set it to `true` at the appropriate time (I'm guessing after your web service stuff completes).

**ADDED**:

To make it so that the selected row cannot be selected again, I would add

Swift:

`var selectedRows = [Int]()`

as an instance variable (i.e. at the class level, not within a method).

Then I would change `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to something like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if !(selectedRows as NSArray).containsObject(indexPath.row) {
        // Request data from web service because this row has not been selected before
        selectedRows.append(indexPath.row) // Add indexPath.row to the selectedRows so that next time it is selected your don't request data from web service again
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    }
}
```

Objective-C:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *selectedRows;`

In the view controller, initialize `selectedRows`:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)selectedRows
{
    if (!_selectedRows) {
        _selectedRows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _selectedRows;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (![self.selectedRows containsObject:indexPath.row]) {
        // Request data from web service because this row has not been selected before
        [self.selectedRows addObject:indexPath.row]; // Add indexPath.row to the selectedRows so that next time it is selected your don't request data from web service again
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }
}
```

Comment: nice answer but another question i have if i checked and send call to webservice then how to stop selecting it again

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question, but every time `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called, `tableView.allowsSelection` will be set to `false`. I assume that you don't want the user to select anything while the web service is fetching the data, right? so only set `allowsSelection` to `true` after you get your data from the web service in whatever method receives the data from the web server.

Comment: yes u didn't understood my question i'm selecting a row and on selecting i'm calling webservice which sends data to server

Problem: how to stop selecting already selected row in did select row

Comment: I see what you're asking. So after a cell is selected, it should no longer be selectable, right? I would create an instance variable like `var selectedRows = [Int]()` (at the class level) and then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` I would store the `indexPath.row` of the selected row in the `selectedRows` array with `selectedRows.append(indexPath.row)`. Then, in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` I would check to make sure that the selected cell is not in the instance variable `selectedRows` by doing something like `if !(selectedRows as NSArray).contains(indexPath.row)`.

Comment: If the selected row's `indexPath.row` is not in the array, that means it hasn't been selected before, so you'd want to run your networking code.

Comment: what is var means variable or array

Comment: `var` indicates a variable, but the `[Int]()` creates and tells the compiler that this is an `Array` variable that holds `Int`s.

Comment: No, defining `var selectedRows = [Int]()` at the class level (i.e. not in a method) in a view controller cannot generate an error.

Comment: please can u post another answer on it i'm getting use of undeclared variable var

Comment: i'm using objective c not swift yaar sorry for not mentioning that

Comment: Added the Objective-C equivalent. Hope it helps and best of luck!

Comment: @trevroj tnx for ur reply but  if (![self.selectedRows containsObject:indexPath.row]) line thorws error

Comment: You need to initialize `self.selectedRows`. I updated the code. That should help.