# How to select radio button at a time in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, radio-button

I am having a radio button in table view cell. This is my radio button

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    if(cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        UIButton *newRadioButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        newRadioButton.frame = CGRectMake(30, 0, 15, 14.5);
        [newRadioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [newRadioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        cell.accessoryView = newRadioButton;

        if ([indexPath isEqual:selectedIndex]) 
        {
            newRadioButton.selected = YES;
        } 
        else 
        {
            newRadioButton.selected = NO;
        }
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedIndex = indexPath;
    [table reloadData];
}

-(void)radiobtn:(id)sender
{
    if([sender isSelected])
    {
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    } else
    {
        [sender setSelected:YES];
    }
}
```

Its working,But i want to select only one radio button at a time like this image (left). But for me selecting all the radio button (right).

[image: image correct]   [image: image wrong]

I need to make it look like the first image.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try:

**in YourViewController.h**

```
  @interface YourViewController : UITableViewController {
     NSIndexPath *selectedIndex
    }
```

**in YourViewController.m**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
        if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
        UIButton *newRadioButton;
        newRadioButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        newRadioButton.frame = CGRectMake(30, 0, 15, 14.5);
        [newRadioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [newRadioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        cell.accessoryView = newRadioButton;
     }
       if ([indexPath isEqual:selectedIndex]) {
         newRadioButton.seleted = YES; 
       } else {
         newRadioButton.seleted = NO;
       }
   cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
  }
```

and

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        selectedIndex = indexPath;
        [tableView reloadData];
 }
```

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959950/iphone-uitableview-cellaccessory-checkmark/5960016#5960016) may help you

Comment: @GowthamK I know why. You don't need add selector for newRadioButton anymore  remove 

    -(void)radiobtn:(id)sender

 and      

     [newRadioButton addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: i have removed that bro, but now radio button is not changing

Comment: @GowthamK see my edited. replace your cellForRowAtIndexPath: code with mine

Comment: I have changed once again your edited code, still is not working, why ?

Comment: see my code not have         cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
and if ([indexPath isEqual:selectedIndex])  not in if(cell == nil) 
    {}

Comment: bro i have deleted cell.selectinstyle and if condition is out of the if(cell == nil). i replace your code only, its not working

Comment: did you load cell from storyboard ?

Comment: no my table view is programatically done. this like i set my table view self.table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, 0) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.table.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    self.table.dataSource = self;
    self.table.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.table];

Answer (score 0):

Unselect all the radio buttons before your if statement using something like this:

```
for (UITableViewCell *cell in [self visibleCells]) {
    [[cell accessoryView] setSelected:NO];
}
```

Comment: in your radiobtn method before your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the button in cellForRowAtindexpth, attach an unique feature by which you can identify which button is being tapped. To do this UIButton has tag property

you need to set the tag for everybutton inside cellForRowAtindexpth, something like

```
// where i is just a static int variable for holding the count

myRadioButton.tag = i ;
 i=i+1
```

now you when you tap based on tag, you can check which button is pressed and you can select that one 
to know which button is pressed u can know like this

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"%d", [button tag]);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reuse button

> Solution: we can add & access controls by tag from view
>
> 1. if control found by tag we can use it.
> 2. if control not found we have to add it with tag.

```
UIButton *newRadioButton = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;
if (!newRadioButton || ![newRadioButton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
    UIButton *newRadioButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    newRadioButton.frame = CGRectMake(30, 0, 15, 14.5);
    [newRadioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [newRadioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    cell.accessoryView = newRadioButton;
}
```