# tableview with multiple sections only select one row in each section

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have tableview with custom cells with multiple sections. There are multiple rows in every section. Each row contains one label and one button(radio). I have created IBOutlet action of the button. My requirement is to select only one label in each section. To resolve this I have implemented below code.
Another issue is that if I select one radio button and scroll to another section, the radio button should be shown as selected. How to resolve this issue, please tell me.

```
let position: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: table_view)
if let indexPath = table_view.indexPathForRowAtPoint(position)
{
    let cell = (table_view.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as! PartCell)
    let Section_count = table_view.numberOfSections
    let rowCount = table_view.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section)
    for j in 0..<Section_count
    {
       if j==indexPath.section
       {
          for i in 0..<rowCount
          {
              if i==indexPath.row
              {
                cell.btn_radio.selected=true
              }
              else
              {
                cell.btn_radio.selected=false
              }
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: can't get your problem. Please explain more & in straight way.

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta http://stackoverflow.com/a/28624956/1882271

Comment: my problem is in a tableview only select one cell of one section at a time. if we select another cell from same section then it will be change or previous is deselect.

Comment: my one problem is resolved but i scroll the view then radio button is unselected again. how to resolve.

Comment: This is happening because the TableView's cells gets reused once it goes outside of the screen. You would need to maintain the selected cell in some array of dictionary.

Comment: An easy way is make an array of selected `IndexPaths` and just check `indexPath` is in array then selected if not then not selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve using below example code:

```
 var selectedArray : NSMutableArray!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        selectedArray = NSMutableArray()
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let identifier : String = "reusecell"
      let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier)!

 if (selectedArray? .contains(indexPath))! {
       cell.accessoryType = .checkmark;
        }
          return cell;
     }

  func clickAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
                    let button = sender as? UIButton
                    let cell = button?.superview?.superview as?   UITableViewCell
                    let indexPath = tblview.indexPath(for: cell!)

                    selectedArray! .removeAllObjects()
                    selectedArray! .add(indexPath)
                    tblview .reloadData()
                    print(indexPath?.row)
                }
```

Comment: which problem faced in this code while you are implemented ?

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'NSIndexPath' to expected argument type '@noescape (Element) throws -> Bool' this error shows