# UITableView : select row with checkmark but no highlight

Tags: ios, uitableview, checkmark

**Issue:** I only want to show the selected cells with checkmark. I don't want the grey highlight.
I tried:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone
```

but didn't work.

**Here is the code:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];                           
      }

     ProfileSelection *profile = [self.profileSelections objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     cell.textLabel.text = [profile profileName];
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
     return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self.profileSelectionsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
    ProfileSelection *profile = [self.profileSelections objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.mobileProfileId = [profile.profileId stringValue];
    [_continueButton setEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: What you tried? Where did you use the selectionStyle?

Comment: `selectionStyle` is the right property. If it didn't work, you put it in the wrong place. Show us the code for the method you put that in.

Comment: try adding line `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` inside `if` block, just after cell allocation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But didn't work.

Comment: Did you set up your table view in a storyboard? If so, you can set the selection style property there as well. If you are using a storyboard, I would start by verifying that the desired value for selectionStyle is set there.

Comment: What exactly is not working? From your code it looks like none of the cells should show a highlight, and all of them should show a checkmark. Is that what you intend?

Comment: Did you check my answer

Comment: @geraldWilliam . Yea I did check the selectionStyle on Storyboard. It is set to none.

Comment: @Greg I wanted to show the checkmark after the user has selected a particular row.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. This worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5960016/928599

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `selectionStyle` property should be enough to remove the highlight.

If you want to show the checkmark after the used has selected the row, you need to implement the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:visibleIndexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Swift`, the easiest way is to `deselect a cell without animation` right after it has been selected:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: This is more of a band-aid way of doing the objective.  I would suggest setting the `cell.selectionStyle` to `.None` in `willDisplayCell` so the selection doesn't appear in the first place as Koen suggested.

Answer (score 0):

delete your this function

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Try to use this your problem will be solved

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Checking Table View";
    return cell;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nischal. It didn't work. On selecting it still has the grey background.

Comment: I have modified my code can you copy and paste whole code once

Answer (score 0):

Go to Storyboard. Select your Table View Cell. Set Selection to None. Then add below codes:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
     [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread looks a bit old, but I actually came across a decent solution for this recently. In case anyone stumbles across this thread, I figure I might as well post an answer. Especially since I spent hours trying to track this down.

I can't find my original sources anymore, but here's what I found out:

The highlight is made by a background view on the `UITableViewCell` on the `selectedBackgroundView` property. If we have a subclass of the table cell, we can detect the transition to the editing state with `willTransitionToState:` and set the background view to one that is clear/white instead of the blue/gray styles.

Here's what I ended up doing, and it works pretty well.

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {
    [super willTransitionToState:state];

    // To remove the blue/gray highlight on the table cell when selected,
    // set the selection background to a clear view.

    if (state & UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask) {

        // If we're moving to an edit state, set the custom background view.

        UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [bgView setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [bgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self setSelectedBackgroundView:bgView];

    } else {

        // Otherwise, just remove it completely.
        // The system should handle the rest.

        [self setSelectedBackgroundView:nil];

    }
}
```

The plus side to this over the other solutions I've seen is that this one is quite minimal. No need for tracking instance variables or anything else.